# What is the PHP methodology used in Joomla (OOP or procedural)?

Tags: joomla

I am a newcomer to **Joomla** and I want to know what is the **PHP** methodology that is used by **Joomla** in order to develop the web applications? Is it **OOP PHP** or **Procedural PHP**?

Comment: Hi ShaneC, welcome to Stackoverflow. Is your question referring to what other Developers of Joomla using, or the makers of Joomla themselves? Can you clarify?

Comment: Hi @Francis, I meant the makers of Joomla themselves.

Comment: Joomla is very much OOP.  If you are not yet comfortable with dealing with classes and objects, then you will experience a steep learning curve as you attempt integrate new extensions and modifications to the existing framework.  I didn't downvote your question, but it isn't really a question that is worded in a way to invite valuable answers for this community.  In the future, if you have Joomla-specific questions, I'll recommend that you post them at Jooma Stack Exchange to reach an audience with Joomla-specific expertise.

Comment: @mickmackusa really appreciate the answer and I will keep that point in my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Joomla is made on OOP concept and it follows MVC model. MVC stands for Model View Controller and you can get the details here https://docs.joomla.org/Model-View-Controller. In short the controller picks up the component and its view variables from the url and with help of these variables it fethces the data from the corresponding model and passes the data back to the view. View then displays the required data. The controller is the middlemen between the View and the Model.
Suppose this is a Joomla Link http://yoursite.com/index.php?option=com_hello&view=hello
So the controller picks the component variable which is com_hello and the view variable which is hello. Now in the component com_hello folder there will be a file named hello.php which is the main file of your component. As an example I have given the below code

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Administrator
 * @subpackage  com_hello
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2018 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// Get an instance of the controller prefixed by Hello
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Hello');

// Perform the Request task
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$controller->execute($input->getCmd('task'));

// Redirect if set by the controller
$controller->redirect();
```

Here The `getInstance` static method of the `JControllerLegacy` class will create a controller. It will instantiate a controller object of a class named `HelloController`. Joomla will look for the declaration of that class in `/components/com_hello/controller.php`. 
After the controller is created, the controller job is to execute the task, as defined in the URL: `<yoursite>/joomla/index.php?option=com_hello&task=<task_name>`. If no task is set, the default task is `display`. When display is used, the `view` variable will decide what will be displayed.

The controller might decide to redirect the page, usually after a task like 'save','delete','archive' etc has been completed. The last statement `$controller->redirect();` takes care of this redirection.

The main entry point, hello.php, essentially passes control to the controller, which handles performing the task that was specified in the request. In our case the task is empty so the task defaults to view and the view is `hello`. Our component specific controller doesn't do anything more than the parent class already does, which is why our controller class is empty. So our controller.php looks like this

```
class HelloController extends JControllerLegacy
{
}
```

The JControllerLegacy class has such a task. In our example, it will display a view named Hello.
view.html.php

```
class HelloViewHello extends JViewLegacy
{
    function display($tpl = null)
    {
        // Assign data to the view
        $this->msg = 'Hello';

        // Display the view
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

The view sets up the text to be output and then calls the base display class. `JViewLegacy` is a base class for a Joomla! View. In our case, this method will display data using the `tmpl/default.php` file.

Our default.php will look like this below

```
<h1><?php echo $this->msg; ?></h1>
```

This is just a simple explanation of how Joomla MVC works. I could have simply given  the links but the links many times breaks or the site is down. But this is the page from where I copied most of the codes https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_a_view_to_the_site_part

You can also check this slink to better understand MVC pattern https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3912211/Principles-Of-MVC-for-PHP-Developers.htm